# Create a simple jdbc transaction inside hibernate transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions, hql

I am not sure about my chances, but i needed to incorporate one JDBC transaction with hibernate transaction. The transactions should get committed only when both the transactions get execute successfully. But looks like due to auto commit is false the JDBC transaction is locking the table and i ended up with the exception

```
12:47:52,605  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 41000
12:47:52,605 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Below is the method

```
@Transactional
public void myMthod(int fieldId, int currentActiveOrgId, int formId)
{
    Savepoint savePoint = null;
    String savepointName = null;
    try{

        //Set auto commit false for sql statemnt
        getDBConnection().setAutoCommit(false);

        savepointName = "deleteDynamicField"+this.getClass().hashCode();
        savePoint = getDBConnection().setSavepoint(savepointName);
        DynamicQueryManager obj = DynamicQueryMgrObjFactory.getDynamicQueryMgrObj(currentActiveOrgId, formId);

         //Resposible for sql statement 
        obj.deleteDynTblRec(fieldId);

        //Resposible for hql transaction (part of the code generating exception)
        dynDao.deleteDynamicField(fieldId);

        DynamicQueryUtil.getDBConnection().commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            logger.error("", e);
            DynamicQueryUtil.getDBConnection().rollback(savePoint);
            DynamicQueryUtil.getDBConnection().releaseSavepoint(savePoint);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Failed to do rollback for savePoint "+savepointName+" ", ex);
        }
    }finally{
        try{
            DynamicQueryUtil.getDBConnection().commit();
            DynamicQueryUtil.getDBConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the complete stack trace

```
  org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:84)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:259)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1141)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:94)
at com.bredge.peer.platform.dynamicdata.dao.DynamicDataDaoImpl.deleteDynamicField(DynamicDataDaoImpl.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
at $Proxy113.deleteDynamicField(Unknown Source)
at com.bredge.peer.platform.dynamicdata.service.DynamicDataServiceImpl.deleteDynamicField(DynamicDataServiceImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy114.deleteDynamicField(Unknown Source)
at com.bredge.peer.platform.dynamicdata.controller.DyanmicDataController.deleteDynamicField(DyanmicDataController.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:233)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:75)
... 50 more
```

Here i wanted to create one simple JDBC transaction inside hibernate transaction, so that if any exception happens it will roll back JDBC transaction as well as hibernate transaction. And yes due to certain limitation of application, i can't migrate sql part of the JDBC code to the hibernate. 
Thanks in advance.**stack overflow** is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new transaction in your example starts on another database connection. Nested transactions are possible only on the same connection and not all databases support them. Your only chance is to grab the connection from the Hibernate session and to perform your JDBC operations on it.

Hibernate incapsulates the database connection for a Hibernate session, but you can get around this if you implement a custom Hibernate session factory.